# How to create a coverage report as html format in react test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, code-coverage

Currently i am trying to create a coverage report as html format in react test case.
how to create it?

here is my test script and coverage

```
"test": "CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"coverage": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage --coverageDirectory=output/coverage/report",
```

using this command it generate coverage as xml format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `--reporters='html'` as a config in coverage script.

The final script looks something like this:

```
"coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --reporters='html' --coverageDirectory='output/coverage/report'"
```

Note: Using create-react-app, you can pass in command line options listed on Jest site. Refer below issue on github for more inof on this:

[Allow configuring reporters for Jest](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2474)